# Authentication via HTTP on VPN

Tags: http, vpn, oauth2

There is an authentication server (OAuth2) that is only accessible from private network.
A customer wants me to implement an app where users use VPN to authenticate themselves on such a server via HTTP (specifically not HTTPS)
I am not a security expert, but have a bad feeling about this. Is it safe? If not, what are the dangers of this approach?

Note: The app will be running on Android devices

Comment: So that'd be HTTP over an encrypted VPN tunnel?

Comment: I have to ask, why not HTTPS?

Comment: @Tangui Yes, that's correct

Comment: @MechMK1 They say it's secure because they are using the VPN, I don't think so, but I am not so sure and that's why I am here. I will try to make them use HTTPS when I have arguments to work with.

Comment: That's still not a good point against it. A VPN is just an encrypted tunnel to your network. Even internal applications should be secured with HTTPS, or else everybody in your network (including an attacker) can read and modify all the traffic to and from the application. And again, why *not* HTTPS? It costs literally nothing, and the computational overhead is completely negligible these days.

Comment: Deploying HTTPs everywhere on your internal network *has* a cost. It's very typical on internal information systems to not have TLS enabled everywhere for this reason.

Comment: @Tangui That is true, but only if the necessary infrastructure to generate and deploy certificates automatically is not in place yet - which is something that should exist.

Comment: I disagree, security is all about making trade-offs. If the costs exceeds the risks, then deploying such an infrastructure may not be worth it. Certificate management is hard, costly and the slightest mistake can have your whole infrastructure down (especially with micro-services and all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider that the network between the VPN's endpoint and the OAuth2 server is safe (because request are reencrypted, or it's a "trusted network"), then an HTTPS tunnel or a VPN tunnel offers the same level of security (encryption and authentication).

However, as stated in [section 3.1.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1.2.1) of the OAuth2 RFC:

> The redirection endpoint SHOULD require the use of TLS as described
> in Section 1.6 when the requested response type is "code" or "token",
> or when the redirection request will result in the transmission of
> sensitive credentials over an open network.

So it's highly recommended to have the OAuth2 server protected with TLS. If it's not, some credentials could be intercepted on the local network of the company in case of misconfiguration of some network equipment.

Also not that OAuth2 expect to have TLS everywhere, so some things can actually not work. For instance, some libraries could refuse to use some endpoints of `/.well-known/openid-configuration` if it's not HTTPS.

So: it's highly recommended to enable HTTPS on your OAuth2 server, but in your case it is not mandatory.